# What recommended machine learning libriries to use?

Tags: machine-learning, mahout

I used Mahout, it is great , but need something better that have more implemented algorithms and maybe faster

Comment: That's very broad... define better, what algorithms, what size data, etc.

Comment: +1 to Sean. Moreover, it is better to specify your platform or other restrictions

Comment: @sean is there any forum to ask for mahout ?

Comment: @sean is is different than http://www.manning-sandbox.com/forum.jspa?forumID=623 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the OS side there's [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/index.html), with a large collection of algorithms across learning disciplines.

Comment: I used Weka but it don't have Collaborative filtering algorithms and also little bit slow